# Set of discontinuities for Thomae's function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

For this question, label:
**Part A**: [Is $f(x,y)$ integrable? Question $3$-$7$ from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534369) 
**Part B**: [Prove $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ is integrable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676505)

For part A and B question, I believe that the set of points of discontinuity is exactly equal to $[0,1]\times [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ because part A is the extension of [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and part B is produced by taking a cross product of [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

But when I use the sequential continuity definition, I get a larger set.
*For Eg*: For this part A; Let $p_n$ be a sequence of rational points converging to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ but the sequence $f\left(p_n,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't converge to zero i.e. $f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$

Is there something wrong with the method? Else if the set is larger, what does the set look like?

I have asked this question on MSE but didn't get any answer and couldn't start a bounty due to reputation restrictions. Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your idea seems to be based on the fallacious assumption that if $f_1, f_2$ have discontinuity sets $D_1, D_2$ respectively, then the discontinuity set of $f(x,y) = f_1(x) + f_2(y)$ will be the product $D_1 \times D_2$, i.e. that $f$ is discontinuous at $(x,y)$ iff **both** the functions $f_1, f_2$ are discontinuous at $x,y$ respectively.  But in fact the "both" should be "either".

Comment: @NateEldredge As the user has shown that for part A, $f(x,y)$ is discontinuous at $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2})$ but in this case, $f_1(x)$ is continuous at $x\in [0,1]$. So, I suppose there is something more to it other than just the replacement of **"both" with "either"**.